# Alter existing page contents based on url

Tags: filters, pages, actions

I have a created a `stuff` page in WP.

When a user visits `stuff/foo`, I'm want to fetch some data from an API append it to the contents of the `stuff` page.

So far I've tried:

- hooking into `the_content` filter but it's not working because WP
  already decides that the page doesn't exist and returns a 404.
- using `init_query_var` and reset the query inside to `$query->set('pagename', 'stuff')`. However, this forces WP to redirect to the `/stuff` page.

Thanks for looking

Comment: You'll probably want to look into [rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) to make that possible.

Answer (score 1):

I belive this will work for you:

Create a "page" called "stuff", then create another page called "foo", make it child of "stuff", now `stuff/foo` will exist and won't be 404.

Finally use `the_content` filter and make the required data manipulation.

The other choice (hard way) you'd have is to use [pre_get_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook, so you can make wordpress believe it's really "foo" page that's being requested, and avoid 404.

Answer (score 0):

One way that you could do this is to use a short code that would depend on the parameter passed through.

For example, use

> https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars

to allow the parameter to be passed into the page. ie:

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "query";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

[Rewrite Rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) can be used to remove the query string and create a fake page `foo/bar`

You can then create a [short code](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) that would pull the data back from the api based on this query var.

for example: `[display-content]` might use the query string `baz` to pull back content from an api. `baz` would be set via a Rewrite Rule which would mask the `?baz=` element off of the url.